# Is it possible to map a leaflet provider (precipitation) on top of a polygon in an interactive map?

Tags: r, leaflet, layers, basemap

I've just started using the `leaflet` package in R to create interactive maps and I'm wondering if it's possible to plot one of the leaflet providers on top of a plotted polygon rather than under it as a basemap. Here's some example code:

```
library(raster)
library(leaflet)

ph <- getData("GADM", country = "PHL", level = 1)

leaflet(data = ph) %>%
  addProviderTiles("OpenWeatherMap.Precipitation") %>% 
  addPolygons(fillColor = "red", 
              fillOpacity = 1, 
              color = "#FFFFFF", 
              weight = 1.3)
```

This simply plots a shapefile of the Philippines (in my real example, it's a choropleth map). The precipitation basemap was found [here](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/) (toward the bottom of the list; OpenWeatherMap.Precipitation). Here's what the output looks like:

[image]

It might be a little difficult to see, but the precip layer is plotted as a basemap, so all of that info is going under the ph shapefile. I'm trying to find a way so that the precipitation layer goes OVER the Philippines shapefile. I'm not sure if this is even possible, but it seems like I should be able to have a plain OSM basemap with the shapefile plotted on top and the precipitation layer on top of the .shp. As it is now, I know that I can alter the opacity of the shapefile, but this isn't much of a solution for a detailed choropleth map. Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: Though I don't know what the equivalent R code would be, here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/dcu9pz2w/) (idea adapted from [this Block](http://bl.ocks.org/jfirebaugh/5380413)) of how to bring a tile layer to the top in `leaflet.js`. It uses the `tileLayer.setZIndex` method as well as the internal `map._createPane` method, which might not be readily accessible in Leaflet for R.

Answer (score 2):

This has now been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881007/how-to-addtiles-on-top-of-addpolygons-in-rs-leaflet, with `addMapPane` function.

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary solution, you could simply do the following

```
library(mapview)
m <- mapview(ph, map.types = "OpenWeatherMap.Precipitation")
m
```

and manually deselect the `ph` polygons from the list of layers in the top-left corner.

[image: map]

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this, but with data from WorldClim.
This is the code I used to get the desired result:

```
library(rgdal)
library(RCurl)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
library(owmr)
library(raster)
library(RColorBrewer)
setwd("D:/Works/Fernando/CRS/R/shapes/")
getwd()
file.exists(".","contorno.shp")
ph <- raster::getData('worldclim',var='tmin',res=0.5, lon=-86.921641,lat=14.761664)
pais<-rgdal::readOGR(dsn=getwd(),layer="contorno")
zona<-rgdal::readOGR(dsn=getwd(),layer="La_Paz_Valle")
#newproj <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
crs(ph$tmin1_23)
crs(pais)
prj<-"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
pais2<-spTransform(pais,crs(prj))
zona2<-spTransform(zona,crs(prj))
crs(pais2)
cp<-crop(ph$tmin1_23,pais2)
s<-stack(ph$tmin1_23)
coors<-read.csv("sequia.csv")
coords<-data.frame(lon=coors$LONGITUDE, lat=coors$LATITUDE)
coordinates(coords)<-c("lon","lat")
val<-extract(x=ph$tmin1_23, y=coords)
#proj4string(xy) <- CRS(prj)  ## for example
#sfc<-st_sfc(xy,prj)
#xy<-data.frame(x=coors$LONGITUDE,Y=coors$LATITUDE)
#require(sf)
#res<-SpatialPoints(cbind(coors$LONGITUDE, -coors$LATITUDE), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat"))
#as(res,"SpatialPoints")
#rasValue<-lapply(ph$tmin1_23,extract, res)
colores <- c('red', 'green', 'blue', 'chocolate', 'deeppink', 'grey')
at <- seq(0, 4800, 800)
cb <- colorBin(palette = colores, bins = at, domain = at)
m<-leaflet() %>%
  addTiles()%>%
  addRasterImage(cp,opacity = 0.8)%>%
  addLegend(pal = cb, values = at)%>%
  addPolygons(data = zona2,fillColor = "#ff0000",opacity = 0.1)
m<-addMarkers(m,lng=coors$LONGITUDE,lat=coors$LATITUDE,popup=paste("Region:",coors$Municipality,"<br>",
                                                                   "Precipitacion:","<br>",
                                                                   val,"mm/mes"))
#m<-addMarkers(m,lng=-87.8333,lat = 14.1167,popup=paste("Guajiquiro","prec:",val,sep = " "))
#m<-addMarkers(m,lng = -87.7,lat = 13.9667,popup="San Juan")
#m<-addMarkers(m,lng = -87.95,lat = 14.0667,popup = "Santa Ana")
#m<-addMarkers(m,lng = -87.5333,lat = 13.65,popup = "San Francisco de Coray")
#m<-addMarkers(m,lng = -87.6525,lat = 13.62083,popup = "Langue")
#m<-addMarkers(m,lng = -87.7167,lat = 13.7333,popup = "Aramecina")
#m %>% mapview(ph, map.types = "OpenWeatherMap.Precipitation")
m
```